# Geom_point with several observations per variable: How to dodge position and change colours (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a coefficient plot in R using ggplot2. Since I already calculated the data, I'm using geom_point and geom_errorbarh. Since I want to include two models/groups per variable, I'm trying to put the coefficients and intervals below each other and changing their colours. Unfortunately, I didn't find out how either of this works.

I know that I am supposed to use something like colour=... or scale_colour_manual(values=...) but then I get the error message "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data".

For the dodging I've already tried geom_point(position=dodge) but R doesn't seem to know this command anymore.

```
example<-data.frame(group=c("group1", "group2", "group1", "group2"),
                variable=c("variable1", "variable1", "variable2", "variable2"),
                value=c(0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2),
                min=c(0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1),
                max=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3))

groupcolor<-c("group1"="red", "group2"="purple")

ggplot(example, aes(x=value, y=variable))+
     theme_bw()+
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0,0.6,0.2), limits=c(0.0, 0.6))+
     geom_point(size=2)+
     scale_colour_manual(values=groupcolor)+
     geom_errorbarh(mapping=aes(xmin=min, xmax=max), height=0.1)
```

This is the code I'm using. I want a plot with the two variables on the y-axis, the coefficients and their intervals on the x-axis and for each variable I want two coefficients: one in red (group1), one in purple (group2). I want them to be below each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do to get close to your ideal output.

```
dodge <- .5 # for consistancy between layers

ggplot(example, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size=2,
             position = position_dodge(width = dodge)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), width = 0.1,
                 position = position_dodge(width = dodge)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=groupcolor) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0,0.6,0.2), limits=c(0.0, 0.6)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I switched to building the plot vertically them flipping the axis at the end, via `coord_flip()`, because `position_dodge()` only allows you to dodge on "width". The bit about `position = "dodge"` does work on certain geoms, but doesn't give you the fine-tune control of the amount to dodge by, like the full function does. Let me know if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. I didn't know it wasn't possible to dodge on "height". And also the colors work now!

Comment: the color is working because now you are telling ggplot you want it mapped from the data with `aes(..., color = group)` Once it knows about that, then it will pay attention to the scale you specified.